# How to define xpath for below xml data? 

Tags: xml, xpath

### I have a xml data as below:

```
<list>
    <com.domain.Products>
        <cla__id>
          <cname>class1</cname>
          <id>1</id>
        </cla__id>
        <name>pname1</name>
        <id>1</id>
    </com.domain.Products>

    <com.domain.Products>
        <cla__id reference="../../com.domain.Products/cla__id"/>
        <name>pname2</name>
        <id>2</id>
    </com.domain.Products>
</list>
```

---

I want to use the xpath to get the value for cname node (the value is 'class1'), while for the second com.domain.Products node, it just has a reference to the cla__id node, which is exactly the same as the one of first com.domain.Products node...

So, the cname for the second com.domain.Products node is actually the same as first com.domain.Products node, both are 'class1', but if I use cla__id/cname xpath to get the value, I can only get it correctly for the first com.domain.Products node, second  com.domain.Products node will only have a blank value, which is wrong.

How to achieve the correct result? Thanks a lot.

### attach: My current smartgwt java code doing it this way:

```
......
private ProductsDS(String id) {
String recordName = "com.domain.Products";
setID(id);
setDataFormat(DSDataFormat.XML);
setRecordXPath("//" + recordName);

DataSourceField pkField = new DataSourceField("id", FieldType.INTEGER, "id");
pkField.setHidden(true);
pkField.setPrimaryKey(true);
DataSourceField claIdField = new DataSourceField("cla__id/cname", FieldType.TEXT, "classtype");
claIdField.setValueXPath("cla__id/cname");
......
```

---

ps: just re-edit twice to make the post better..

Comment: Request you to not add lines like "Urgent help needed" in the question

Comment: Can you give a well formed xml?Is your example xml correct?

Comment: just corrected the xml data, now it should be well format

Comment: Desired result is still unclear :(

Comment: Not clear what you mean to ask with the phrase following "while for the second". The first part of your question seems clear - *what is the xpath to get the node with value "class1"*?  The second part is not clear.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explaining the problem and for a proposed easy solution. :)

Comment: re-edit again, now should really be well format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not possible in XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0 to perform dynamic (not contained in the XPath expression, but generated) XPath expressions**.

Therefore, it is not possible to dynamically evaluate a reference to an element, embedded in another XML element, where the reference is an XPath expression.

**Proposed solution:** Provide a new way to uniquely identify an element (such as giving it a unique id attribute) and use the value of this attribute as the reference to the element:

```
<list>
    <com.domain.Products>
        <cla__id>
            <cname>class1</cname>
            <id>1</id>
        </cla__id>
        <name>pname1</name>
        <id>1</id>
    </com.domain.Products>
    <com.domain.Products>
        <cla__id reference="1"/>
        <name>pname2</name>
        <id>2</id>
    </com.domain.Products>
</list>
```

Then, the `cname` value for the `com.domain.Products` element having `id` of `2` is:

```
/*/*
  [id
  = 
   /*/*[id=2]/cla__id/@reference]
                           /cla__id/cname/text()
```

Comment: +1. Or else one could perform 2-phase transformation, generating xslt on the first phase.

Comment: @Flack: Yes, there are more than one non (only) XPath ways to dynamically evaluate an expression, and generating a new XSLT stylesheet is one of them. To see another way of doing this, just have a look at the code of the XPath Visualizer. :)

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. If the xml data can not be modified, then this solution may not acceptable. Actually I am resolving this in java (smartgwt client side), so I can accept the 2-phase transformation. Just want a simple way to do this correctly.

Comment: @xeoshow: You are welcome. BTW, I am not saying that you need to modify the XML document -- just that you may use other data that uniquely identifies the referenced node -- such as its `id` child.

Comment: +1 Correct answer and good advice: use IDREF for crossreferences in XML documents.

Comment: @xeoshow: And as @Alejandro reminds us, if the XML document has a DTD in which the `id` attribute has been specified the `ID` type, then one can even use the very convenient in this case, standard XPath function `id()`.

Comment: @xeoshow:  Yes. I suppose that the `id` element is unique (different for different elements).

Comment: Thanks all for your kind help, while how to use the IDREF ? What is exactly the xpath for this then? Sorry for the newbie question..

Comment: @xeoshow: It is better to ask new questions as ...  new questions. :)